# Take photo with iPhone and then use it!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app that takes a photo and puts it in an image view. Simple.
Code looks like this:

```
- (void)takePhoto:(id)sender
{
    // Lazily allocate image picker controller
    if (!imagePickerController) {
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        // If our device has a camera, we want to take a picture, otherwise, we just pick from
        // photo library
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        }else
        {
            [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        }

        // image picker needs a delegate so we can respond to its messages
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
    }
    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    image = [ImageHelpers imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(480, 640)];

    [imageView setImage:image];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I use the Camera Roll everything works great, but if I use the actual Camera the image view is just black. Why is that?

Do I need to save it to the camera roll before I use it in the image view?

Comment: Set a breakpoint to check if image is nil when it's passed to ImageHelpers

Comment: No it seems to not be nil. I can save the photo to the camera roll using: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() so the image exists in the variable. It seems to get lost when I assign it to the imageView.

Comment: I guess I have to save it somewhere before I send it to my view. What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Found the solution myself.

I had to dismiss the modal view first...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //Do this first!!
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    image = [ImageHelpers imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(480, 640)];

    [imageView setImage:image];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't just use that code?

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: Well, it was deprecated in iOS 3... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:

Comment: Ok. I still don't want to use a deprecated function ;)